# QT Resource File - Images Not Showing When Running

Tags: c++, image, qt, resources

I just upgraded to QT Creator 5.3 and created a brand new QT Widgets Application project and am using the Microsoft VC++ compiler. All I have is a resource file with "logo.png" added (which opens in QT if I double click it), and a label that I am trying to set the background image for. The problem is that no matter what I do I cannot get the image to show up when the program is running. The only way I can get it to show the image is by not using the resource file and instead map directly to the file (ex. "c:/blah/blah/logo.png")

Also, if I set the background image in the UI designer, the background shows up in the IDE but NOT when I run the program. I have tried probably 20+ variations of the code, including resource file aliases as well as adding the files to the project directly, and nothing seems to work.

I'm not sure if there is a step I am missing, or if perhaps there is something that I have to do to get the project to compile the image.

**Resources.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**loginform.cpp**

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap (":/logo.png");
ui->label->setPixmap( QPixmap(pixmap));
```

**Project.pro**

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    logo.png

RESOURCES += \
    Resources.qrc
```

Comment: Try deleting all of the build folders and building your project anew. Try adding a non-existent file to `Resources.qrc` to verify how the build fails if `qrc` can't find the file.

Comment: I tried adding a file "logo1.png" which doesn't exist to the resource file and it built with no errors.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that resources cannot be placed at "top level" in the resource. You have to provide some non-empty name for the prefix. Try if it helps.

Comment: Is logo.png in the same directory as your qrc file?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory as the qrc file, and I have tried naming the directory differently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After countless hours of trial, error, and mostly frustration, I have been able to resolve this issue by simply running qmake.

To do this I just right clicked on the project and clicked "Run qmake" and suddenly the image errors (as well as a few others) were resolved!

Comment: why qmake is not automatically run?! Thanks it helped me too.